# Google console trouble with outh

Tags: google-api, google-authentication, google-console-developer

I have a google application. Right now all my auth in nodejs working well. But when I'm trying to login using google I have an error that "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app"
I've tried to find where I can enable auth, but no solution.

I think that it is a problem with google console settings.

How should it work? - I need to log in with my google account

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the google+ API is enabled?

Comment: Sorry for the question, but where can I check it? It should be enabled, It worked but only with one custom e-mail

Comment: You can check that from the [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com). Then go to "Library" & search Google Plus.

Comment: It's enabled. Created a new APP. :(